# how to convert a dynamically allocated array of pointers (to object) into a single pointer to object?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have written a code in C++ in which there are arrays of pointers to objects which are given to a function as argument as the simple code bellow:

```
void foo1(myClass **obj1)
{
    //some stuff here
    foo2(obj[0]);
}

void foo2(myClass *obj)
{
    //some other stuff here
    cout<<"I'm here"<<endl;
}

main()
{
    myClass **object
    object= new *myClass[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        object[i]=new myClass()
    foo1(object);
    cout<<"done"<<endl;
}
```

This code works until printing "I'm here" and suddenly crashes. I think there should be something wrong with the arrays of arrays of the pointers and the fact that I converted a myclass ** to myclass *. But I can't figure what's the problem, exactly.

**EDITED:** I Marked The code in foo2 and poof!!! It worked just fine. To my strange it showed to me that execution line can pass the code and execute some line (e.g. cout<<"I'm here") despite the fact that an illegal memory access error has been reached before. Am I correct?

Comment: Post a complete, compilable example.

Comment: how does the myClass look like ?

Comment: You should not use pointers in C++ unless you have a very good reason to.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya it's a big class containing 2D dynamically allocated arrays, vectors and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code is riddled with multiple typos and errors that prevents it from being compiled. Fixing all of the typos produced the following result:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass {};

void foo2(myClass *obj)
{
    //some other stuff here
    cout<<"I'm here"<<endl;
}

void foo1(myClass **obj)
{
    //some stuff here
    foo2(obj[0]);
}

main()
{
    myClass **object;
    int n=10;
    object= new myClass *[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        object[i]=new myClass();
    foo1(object);
    cout<<"done"<<endl;
}
```

This ran without crashing, and valgrind showed no illegal memory access or any other problems (sans the memory leak).

Whatever your problem is, is somewhere else. Except for the errors that prevented it from getting compiled, there are no issues with this code. No answer is possible, without seeing compilable code that crashes, as advertised.

Comment: Is there a possibility of any illegal memory access or so before that "I'm here"? I mean execution first read and run the lines before that cout and if there is any error, it should be not displayed. Right?

Comment: It has compile errors, That's right. I assumed that one would know the prerequisites for the code to be compiled.

Comment: Illegal memory access is possible at any time. An illegal memory access does not necessarily result in the application stopping immediately. 'const char *foobar="foobar"; const int *p=*(const int **)foobar;' Patently illegal, but this will run on most platforms without crashing, and the crash will only occur in some entirely different part of the program, which tries to use the pointer. Welcome to C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had made mistake with using the unspecified variable space, regarding the resizing of a vector. It was quite surprising for me at the moment that a cout stream can do its jo, while a illegal memory access has occurred.